# Android: Paypal Merchant Id error as invalid Credentials

Tags: android, paypal

I am new to android and done paypal integration using sandbox id but when I use the production environment it will crash and come out and when i check the logcat i will get the error as this below

```
06-18 07:09:40.221: W/DefaultRequestDirector(3943): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
06-18 07:09:40.591: W/paypal.sdk(3943): aa SN:35 PayPal Debug-ID: 7d7a3da2bf9aa [live, 2.2.2;release]
06-18 07:09:40.591: E/paypal.sdk(3943): request failure with http statusCode:401,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
06-18 07:09:40.641: E/paypal.sdk(3943): request failed with server response:{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials are invalid"}
06-18 07:09:40.641: E/PayPalService(3943): invalid_client
```

But the client id which i am using in this app is the correct one but i am getting an error using the 
production id. Can anyone tell me why this happens and how paypal SDK works

paypal code

```
package com.coded.sandeep;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation; 
public class PaypalActivity extends Activity {


    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;

    // note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "AfZKkxA3Detdl4CgpOKoDMUVTSn3VHq633qkQp_F5hL520589653";


    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
    .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
    .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.paypal_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(PaypalActivity.this, PayPalService.class);

        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        startService(intent);
    }

    public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {

        PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(PaypalActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }

     private PayPalPayment getThingToBuy(String paymentIntent) {

        Intent intent1 = getIntent();

        String message = "people"
        String amount = "1.26"



        return new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(amount), "GBP", message,
                paymentIntent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {

                    Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
        }
        else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I am doing an Paypal integration for an android application but when i used the `ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION` and add the live id which i have created in PayPal i have added in the `Config_client_id` but after adding my app is getting crashed and popping an error as "merchant id is invalid" how can i rectify this I have posted the code below which i am using it.

But when i use the `SANDBOX ENVIRONMENT` this below code is working fine with no errors

Comment: @Rutvij can u pls tell what is wrong with the client id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try full code and sanbox Id or client Id is different:-

```
    import java.io.StringReader;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Html;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
    import com.coloruapp.model.utilities.Constant;
    import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalAuthorization;
    import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
    import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity;
    import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
    import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
    import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
    import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

    public class PayPalMainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        /*
         * - Set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION to move real money.
         * 
         * - Set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to use your test credentials from
         * https://developer.paypal.com
         * 
         * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK to kick the tires without communicating
         * to PayPal's servers.
         */
        private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;

        // note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.


        private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "Your client id";        //Live Id


        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;


        private static PayPalConfiguration config;


        final Context context = this;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_pal_integration);


              config = new PayPalConfiguration()
             .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
             .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
             // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
             .merchantName("Your Merchent Name")
             .defaultUserEmail("Your Email id")
             .languageOrLocale("Your set Language");
             //.merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
             //.merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));




            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
            intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
            startService(intent);
        }


        public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
            // change PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE to PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE to only authorize payment and capture funds later.
            PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(1.26)), "GBP", "people",
                PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(PayPalMainActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
        }

        public void onFuturePaymentPressed(View pressed) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PayPalMainActivity.this, PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.class);

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                            .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                    if (confirm != null) {
                        try {
                            Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));


                            Toast.makeText(PayPalMainActivity.this, "Payment Successful. You will receive an email shortly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            //Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
                } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                    Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid Payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
                }
            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    PayPalAuthorization auth = data
                            .getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
                    if (auth != null) {
                        try {
                            Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", auth.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                            String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                            Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", authorization_code);

                            sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Future Payment code received from PayPal",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("FuturePaymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "The user canceled.");
                } else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                    Log.i("FuturePaymentExample",
                            "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
                }
            }
        }

        private void sendAuthorizationToServer(PayPalAuthorization authorization) {

            // TODO:
            // Send the authorization response to your server, where it can exchange the authorization code
            // for OAuth access and refresh tokens.
            //
            // Your server must then store these tokens, so that your server code can execute payments
            // for this user in the future.

        }

        public void onFuturePaymentPurchasePressed(View pressed) {
            // Get the Application Correlation ID from the SDK
            String correlationId = PayPalConfiguration.getApplicationCorrelationId(this);

            Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "Application Correlation ID: " + correlationId);

            // TODO: Send correlationId and transaction details to your server for processing with
            // PayPal...
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App Correlation ID received from SDK",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // Stop service when done
            stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
            super.onDestroy();
        }



    }
```

xml code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#161616"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buyItBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onBuyPressed" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: One second i will check and let u know @Rutvij

Comment: It is the same thing @Rutvij Same error invalid client

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: @gung sure i will do it